# WebView:How to detect if I am on the original web page and execute a certain method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have this method that goes back to previous webpage in a web view under certain circumstance and it works fine. However, I want to implement a function that checks if I am on the original web page and if so, when I push the back button it takes me to a navigation view controller. The original page is this code [webView loadHTMLString:self.item.description baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.item.link]];. Now I need to figure out how to check if I am on that page and if so I need to execute this code: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. Any help will be appreciated.

```
- (void)back
{
    if ([webView canGoBack]) {
        [webView goBack];
    } else {
        [webView loadHTMLString:self.item.description baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.item.link]];    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` of `UIWebViewDelegate`  to check what contains in the url. if you find it then just go `NavigationController`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if ([[request.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"http://yourURL"].location!=NSNotFound) {
       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];.    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
       <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

to the header. Then set webView.delegate to yes;

Once you have it set as a delegate, then you can get the absoluteString and the requestURL, and override the method. With the absoluteString you can check for a substring, text, domain, basically anything you want! You override shouldStartLoadWithRequest or webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
   -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
   -(void)shouldStartLoadWithRequest :(UIWebView *)webView
```

That calls everytime any webpage is loaded.