# Bool web view function not working as planned

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Basically, what I want is a function that executes this function `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` when a certain button is pressed and if you are on a Google page. But the function happens even if I am not on a Google page. Is there something I might be missing?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(wasClicked)
    {
        if([[request.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"google"].location!=NSNotFound)
        {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check within this method if button is clicked with `UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted` or link is clicked `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`,

```
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
}
```

you should at least read the documentation of the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) before posting the question for every single step. I am writing this because in the previous question you asked about how it works, you got answer in [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419866/webviewhow-to-detect-if-i-am-on-the-original-web-page-and-execute-a-certain-met) and you copied the answer and pasted as a question here instead of trying it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Google page, there's a strong likelihood that most links will initiate a load request for a URI that contains "google" somewhere in the string. I'm not sure of this, but I think even Google search results first load a Google URL for tracking before redirecting to the actual page clicked.

Try adding `NSLog(@"URL: %@", [request.URL absoluteString]);` to your function and see why that statement is evaluating to `YES`.